# Avoid recursion in rebinding function reference

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, reference

Library `X` repeatedly tries to invoke its method `foo` to the massive detriment of my plugin `Y`'s UX. My plugin `Y` introduces arbitrary logic `shouldFooExecute` that must be considered before `X.foo`'s end results can take place. However, when the user journey through `Y` (takes place in a modal window) is complete, `X` should be able to carry on as though nothing has happened.

```
// This is an external library. I can't modify and shouldn't overwrite it.
x = {
  // A method that completely screws my plugin
  foo: function(){
    /* nasty stuff */
  }
}

// This is my widget!
y = {
  // Init function, called when my plugin boots
  init: function(){
    // This scope handles the x.foo problem
    void function rebindFoo(){
      // Internal state
      var shouldFooExecute = false;
      // I need to be able to refer back to the original foo after I've temporarily rebound it
      var x_foo = x.foo;

      // Re-attach foo to its original definition & context
      function rebindFooToX(){
        // ECMAScript 5 browsers are fine!
        if(Function.prototype.bind){
          // x.foo is literally rebound to pretty much exactly what it was
          x.foo = x_foo.bind(x);
        }
        // Others not so good when this function executes a second time
        else {
          x.foo = function rebound_foo(){
            // An extra scope! Horrible. And it's recursive!
            return x_foo.apply(x, arguments);
          }
        }
      }

      x.foo = function y_foo(){
        // Stop and consider y's esoteric logic
        if(shouldFooExecute){
          // If it's fine, we rebind everything
          rebindFooToX();
          // This will have the intended effect
          x.foo();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes when my plugin is re-initialised on browsers that don't support bind. `x.foo` ends up referencing `rebound_foo` which is circular. Is there any kind of logic I can write to avoid recursion and use the existing `rebound_foo` in cases where it exists?

Comment: Why are you trying to replace x.foo? You might run into issues of other plugins using the function as you bind it, etc. Can't you just call your own y_foo() instead of using x.foo()?

Comment: Also I think `x.foo = y_foo(){` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: @AramKocharyan — thanks for pointing out the typo. Potentially running into issues with other plugins is precisely why I'm going to this length to rebind `x.foo` back to its original context once my modal's UX is finished. I'm not the one trying to call `x.foo` (I don't want to call it!) — the events bound to that are manifold, and out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim to add `Function.prototype.bind` method to browsers that doesn't support it natively.

Comment: The es5-shim bind method, much like underscore's bind method, does the same thing as my code: it creates a _new_ function (`rebound_foo` in my code, `bound` in es5-shim) which _returns_ the original function with its context defined through `apply`. The extra scope is necessary to capture the `arguments` object, since `apply` immediately invokes the function with explicit parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's 7 months after the fact, so this issue is probably OBE, however I wanted to note that depending on how X is defined, you can try inheritance:

```
var x = function() {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log("from x");
    };

    this.bar = function() {
        console.log("from x");
    };
}

var y = function() {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log("from y");
    }
}

y.prototype = new x();

var test = new y();
test.foo(); // will output: from y
test.bar(); // will output: from x
```